# Android: Update UI TextView from dbAdapter

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-sqlite, batch-processing

In my app, I have a `dbAdapter` and one of the functions does a batch update on many rows. Earlier, the data population barely took a few milliseconds and from the main thread, I just called:

`dbAdapter.BatchUpdate();`

However, now the data population within the above function takes many seconds. I have for now shown a `indeterminate progressBar` and am executing the above via `Runnable`.

How can I convert that to a `horizontal progressBar` where I can set the progress based on the number of rows to process and the current row number? Since the function starts and ends with BEGIN and COMMIT, I may not be able to simply pull the number of rows and process row by row (from the UI).

**Edit**

Here's an excerpt of the code...

```
/* In Main Activity */
mlBinding.btnBatchUpdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Runnable batch = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
                dbAdapter.batchUpdate();
            }
        };
        batch.run();
    }
}


/* In DBAdapter Class */
class DBAdapter {
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase dbW;
    private SQLiteDatabase dbR;

    public boolean batchUpdate() {
        try {
            dbW.execSQL("BEGIN;");

            String[] itemsToProcess = getItemsToProcess();
            for (int i=0; i<itemsToProcess.length; i++) {
                //Do some really long stuff here
            }

            dbW.execSQL("COMMIT;");
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a lot of different problems, e.g.

1. `Do some really long stuff here` does the delay (measure by `currentTimeMillis` from java)
2. Communication delay
3. DB executes SQL too long

So you have to localize the problem first...

Comment: I am encrypting the data now, so the encryption part takes time.